# Where is web-based doc for Sonarqube javascript, css, and html checkers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sonarqube

I am looking for something like this:

http://jshint.com/docs/options/

for the Sonarqube equivalent, and also for Sonarqube html and css.  By comparison, this:  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JavaScript+Plugin  is almost useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check on Nemo to browse the list of existing rules:

- [JavaScript](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=js)
- [Web](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=web) (HTML)

The CSS plugin is not installed on Nemo, but you can install it on a recent instance of SonarQube and use the Rules page to browse through the existing rules.